# Regexxer stopped working - it doesn't find the string

Tags: 18.04, regex

Regexxer is a brilliant search-replace tool for multiple files, but suddenly it stopped working August 10. I posted [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/regexxer/bugs/26/) on the Regexxer bug page:

> I used this brilliant program less than 20 hours ago without any problems, but now it doesn't find the text string, although it is taken from one of the files in the left panel. I am using version 0.10-3 installed directly from the Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS repository. I also tried reinstalling it. Didn't help.
>   Please help.

But nobody has answered. 
Am I the only one for whom it stopped working?

For example, this string (taken verbatim from one of the files) isn't found:

```
If you can't see the (Facebook) Comments Box here
```

[image: regexxer screenshot of the above example]

Comment: can you post an example of the search string you are using so I can test it on my machine?

Comment: I don't remember exactly what I searched for, but this simple string (taken from one of the files) isn't found: "If you can't see the (Facebook) Comments Box here". I just posted a screenshot of that in my bug report here: https://sourceforge.net/p/regexxer/bugs/26/ (There doesn't seem to be a way to post attachments here on AskUbuntu.com??)

Comment: According to SourceForge, the last update was 2013-04-17. So I guess the project is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the program installed to test, but from a glance, it appears the problem in your example is the parentheses `()`. In most flavours of regex, parens are special characters that indicate a match group. So try escaping them:

```
If you can't see the \(Facebook\) Comments Box here
```

Otherwise, try a single word for example, like `Facebook` or `Firefox` or something.